# Create a pivot of same columns in to 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I'm using a SQL Server, I've a query which return the data of all the fields, The main thing is that 1 field can belongs to multiple records, the record ID differentiate them.

I've a data set like this.

[This is my current data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meg5y.png)

My current query:

```
Select fd.FieldName ,FV.FieldID, Data , R.RecordID    from FieldValues FV
Inner Join Records R on R.RecordID = FV.RecordID
Inner Join Forms F On f.FormID = R.FormID
Inner join Fields fd on fd.FieldID = fv.FieldID
Where R.RecordID IN (45,46)
```

I need to create 1 row of each columns that belongs to the same RecordID like this.

```
Service Name       Location          city         VendorCode       RecordID

Raj              ABC LOCATION      ABC CITY         32               45
BEN              ABC LOCATION      ABC CITY         --               46
```

The above is my desired output.

I've tried with pivot but have not succeeded.

Comment: What was your attempt? You forgot to include it. Ideally, however, fix your design; this type of design rarely works or performs well in an RDBMS.

Comment: I've so many forms in my project so I've created it with dynamic forms

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Then you need to write lots of dynamic SQL @FaizanNaeem . I doubt you want to do that, as if you knew how to do that you wouldn't be asking the question you are. Fix your design and use a normalised approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to deal with dynamic `pivot` and you do know the key of the rows you want to convert into columns, you can use standard sql with `max` and `case when`

```
select
  max(case fd.FieldName when 'SelectService' then Data else null end) as ServiceName,
  max(case fd.FieldName when 'EnterYourLocation' then Data else null end) as Location,
  max(case fd.FieldName when 'City' then Data else null end) as city,
  max(case fd.FieldName when 'VendorCodeOption' then Data else null end) as VendorCode,
  R.RecordId
from FieldValues FV
  Inner Join Records R on R.RecordID = FV.RecordID
  Inner Join Forms F On f.FormID = R.FormID
  Inner join Fields fd on fd.FieldID = fv.FieldID
where R.RecordID IN (45,46)
group by R.RecordId
```

Comment: this is fulfilling the requirement but not dynamically as I have lots of fields , so I need to create conditions for all those fields?

Comment: I am afraid then that with sql server with simple sql it's not possible. You need to build your query dynamically in order to get in a first stage all your keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution with pivot but it is missing to include adjust joins

```
declare @columns varchar(max) set @columns = '' 
select @columns =  coalesce(@columns + '[' + cast(col as varchar(MAX)) + '],', '') 
FROM ( select FieldName as col from FieldValues group by FieldName ) m

set @columns = left(@columns,LEN(@columns)-1) 
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max);
set @SQLString = '

select * from 
 ( select RecordId, FieldName, Data from FieldValues) m
PIVOT 
(   MAX(Data) 
    FOR FieldName in (' + @columns + ')
) AS  PVT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```